# Make mocha test in particular submodules?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

My app includes a number of smaller modules, in private npm modules under `node_modules/submodulename`. How can I make mocha invoke the tests in particular subfolders?

I've followed https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console)

var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var testModule = function(moduleName){
    var dirName = 'node_modules/'+moduleName

    // Instantiate a Mocha instance.
    var mocha = new Mocha({
        ui: 'tdd'
    });

    // Add each .js file to mocha
    fs.readdirSync(dirName).filter(function(file){
        // Only keep the .js files
        return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
    }).forEach(function(file){
        log('Adding', file)
        mocha.addFile(
            path.join(dirName, file)
        );
    });

    // Run the tests.
    mocha.run(function(failures){
        process.on('exit', function () {
            process.exit(failures);
        });
    });
}

testModule('mycompany-blog')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dir used by `mocha.addFile()` **must be the 'test' dir explicitly**, not the directory containing the test dir:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var testModule = function(moduleName){
    var dirName = 'node_modules/'+moduleName+'/test'

    // Instantiate a Mocha instance.
    var mocha = new Mocha({
        ui: 'tdd'
    });

    // Add each .js file to mocha
    fs.readdirSync(dirName).filter(function(file){
        // Only keep the .js files
        return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
    }).forEach(function(file){
        log('Adding', file)
        mocha.addFile(
            path.join(dirName, file)
        );
    });

    // Run the tests.
    mocha.run(function(failures){
        process.on('exit', function () {
            process.exit(failures);
        });
    });
}
```

I've updated https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically to reflect this.

Answer (score -3):

You must not place your local modules in `node_modules/`.  That folder doesn't go into source control.

What you can do is create a folder `privmod1` and put tests in `privmod1/test` then `cd privmod1` and run mocha.  You want to test that module separately.

Or, you can require/import from parent dirs in files in test like `require('../privmod1')`.

Other options for private modules: just put them in a github repo you have access to and reference with `githubuser/privmod1` or use the official npm private module system.

Comment: That's incorrect: whether any folder goes into source control is entirely up to the user.

Comment: Additionally, the question concerns invoking mocha via JavaScript, not via the shell.

Comment: When you originally posted it and I started answering you didn't include any JavaScript.  Anyway, good for you and have a nice day.  Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: I added code to explain what I'd already tried, as is good manners on stack. You replied a technically incorrect lecture, and 'cd into every folder and run mocha' which is a pretty poor answer even before I added the example.